# Importing attributes to a new magento installation

Tags: attributes, database, import, backup

What are the tables I need to dump to be able to import them in a new installation?
I need this to avoid reinserting all the custom attributes for every new Magento installation.
thanks

Comment: Are you asking about products attributes only or about all EAV entities in general?

Comment: The most elegant way to solve this is to have your attributes scripted. You should create an extension with an install file where you can add all the attributes. This way you make sure the attributes are added to your magento instance when installing the extension. You also have the possibility to version that install script and make it easier to migrate the data.

Comment: @Marius - I like the idea of having a script to manage the products attributes but I am not a programmer. Can I hire u?

Comment: @Tim - Yes it's for product attributes

Comment: @GabrieleCripezzi: I already have a job. I can recommend you this 'gist' that shows you how to add an attribute by code: https://gist.github.com/mikewhitby/1234721

Comment: Thank you Marius but... what should I do with that? :)

Comment: An alternative and slightly less programmatically elegant solution would be to use uRapidFlow Pro to create your attributes using spreadsheet imports which you can run on multiple installations. I'm not sure if it has an attribute export or if you'll have to creat the spreadsheets by hand at least once.

Comment: is there a way to do it via SQL?

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Marius's comment above, the best solution would be an extension which contains setup scripts which insert each of these attributes.  `n98-magerun.phar` can be handy here.  `n98-magerun.phar dev:module:create` can create the basic module structure for you.  Then you can use `n98-magerun.phar dev:setup:script:attribute` to create setup scripts based on existing attributes.  There may be some work required to add a setup resource to your module to make the setup scripts run and to test it all, which will require some programming expertise, but that's where I'd start.

You can find [n98-magerun on github](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun).