# How to export all attributes and attribute sets from one magento installation and import to other installation?

Tags: product-attribute, importexport, attribute-set

I need to export all the product attributes and attribute sets from my current website (Enterprise Edition 1.12.0.0) and import all of them to a new website (CE 1.8).

I've gone through these:

- [Importing attributes to a new magento installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/importing-attributes-to-a-new-magento-installation)
- [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)
- [exporting-and-importing-attributes-in-magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594851/exporting-and-importing-attributes-in-magento)

But **can't figure out how to export all the attributes first** moreover I can't spend money for any extension for this process :( as my company won't provide it.

Can some one point me the right direction?

Comment: All the posts I've gone through focus on importing attributes from CSV (manually prepared) or php script, nothing on extracting attributes and their values from source website.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've done this to export all attributes and their options (if it is a dropdown attribute) from the source website:

> exportAttributes.php in **root directory** of **source website**:

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$entity_type_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();

prepareCollection($entity_type_id);

function prepareCollection($ent_type_id){
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $select_attribs = $connection->select()
            ->from(array('ea'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute')))
            ->join(array('c_ea'=>$resource->getTableName('catalog/eav_attribute')), 'ea.attribute_id = c_ea.attribute_id');
            // ->join(array('e_ao'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option'), array('option_id')), 'c_ea.attribute_id = e_ao.attribute_id')
            // ->join(array('e_aov'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option_value'), array('value')), 'e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and store_id = 0')
    $select_prod_attribs = $select_attribs->where('ea.entity_type_id = '.$ent_type_id)
                                            ->order('ea.attribute_id ASC');

    $product_attributes = $connection->fetchAll($select_prod_attribs);

    $select_attrib_option = $select_attribs
                                ->join(array('e_ao'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option'), array('option_id')), 'c_ea.attribute_id = e_ao.attribute_id')
                                ->join(array('e_aov'=>$resource->getTableName('eav/attribute_option_value'), array('value')), 'e_ao.option_id = e_aov.option_id and store_id = 0')
                                ->order('e_ao.attribute_id ASC');

    $product_attribute_options = $connection->fetchAll($select_attrib_option);

    $attributesCollection = mergeCollections($product_attributes, $product_attribute_options);
    prepareCsv($attributesCollection);

}

function mergeCollections($product_attributes, $product_attribute_options){

    foreach($product_attributes as $key => $_prodAttrib){
        $values = array();
        $attribId = $_prodAttrib['attribute_id'];
        foreach($product_attribute_options as $pao){
            if($pao['attribute_id'] == $attribId){
                $values[] = $pao['value'];
            }
        }
        if(count($values) > 0){
            $values = implode(";", $values);
            $product_attributes[$key]['_options'] = $values;
        }
        else{
            $product_attributes[$key]['_options'] = "";
        }
        /*
            temp
        */
        $product_attributes[$key]['attribute_code'] = $product_attributes[$key]['attribute_code'];
    }

    return $product_attributes;

}

function prepareCsv($attributesCollection, $filename = "importAttrib.csv", $delimiter = '|', $enclosure = '"'){

    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    $first = true;
    foreach ($attributesCollection as $line) {
        if($first){
            $titles = array();
            foreach($line as $field => $val){
                $titles[] = $field;
            }
            fputcsv($f, $titles, $delimiter, $enclosure);
            $first = false;
        }
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter, $enclosure); 
    }
    fseek($f, 0);
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    fpassthru($f);
}
```

This will give a csv file [actually i used "|" to separate ;)]
paste this **csv file in MAGENTO_ROOT/attribImport** directory of the destination website, i.e. website to which attributes need to be imported:

> now put the following code in  MAGENTO_ROOT/attribImport** directory
>   of the destination website

```
<?php
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
// $fileName = MAGENTO . '/var/import/importAttrib.csv';
$fileName = 'importAttrib.csv';
// getCsv($fileName);
getAttributeCsv($fileName);

function getAttributeCsv($fileName){
    // $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($fileName,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
    $file = fopen($fileName,"r");
    while(!feof($file)){
        $csv[] = fgetcsv($file, 0, '|');
    }
    $keys = array_shift($csv);
    foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
        $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
    }
    foreach($csv as $row){
        $labelText = $row['frontend_label'];
        $attributeCode = $row['attribute_code'];
        if($row['_options'] != "")
            $options = explode(";", $row['_options']); // add this to createAttribute parameters and call "addAttributeValue" function.
        else
            $options = -1;
        if($row['apply_to'] != "")
            $productTypes = explode(",", $row['apply_to']);
        else
            $productTypes = -1;
        unset($row['frontend_label'], $row['attribute_code'], $row['_options'], $row['apply_to'], $row['attribute_id'], $row['entity_type_id'], $row['search_weight']);
        createAttribute($labelText, $attributeCode, $row, $productTypes, -1, $options);
    }
}


/**
 * Create an attribute.
 *
 * For reference, see Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::saveAction().
 *
 * @return int|false
 */
function createAttribute($labelText, $attributeCode, $values = -1, $productTypes = -1, $setInfo = -1, $options = -1)
{

    $labelText = trim($labelText);
    $attributeCode = trim($attributeCode);

    if($labelText == '' || $attributeCode == '')
    {
        echo "Can't import the attribute with an empty label or code.  LABEL= [$labelText]  CODE= [$attributeCode]"."<br/>";
        return false;
    }

    if($values === -1)
        $values = array();

    if($productTypes === -1)
        $productTypes = array();

    if($setInfo !== -1 && (isset($setInfo['SetID']) == false || isset($setInfo['GroupID']) == false))
    {
        echo "Please provide both the set-ID and the group-ID of the attribute-set if you'd like to subscribe to one."."<br/>";
        return false;
    }

    echo "Creating attribute [$labelText] with code [$attributeCode]."."<br/>";

    //>>>> Build the data structure that will define the attribute. See
    //     Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController::saveAction().

    $data = array(
                    'is_global'                     => '0',
                    'frontend_input'                => 'text',
                    'default_value_text'            => '',
                    'default_value_yesno'           => '0',
                    'default_value_date'            => '',
                    'default_value_textarea'        => '',
                    'is_unique'                     => '0',
                    'is_required'                   => '0',
                    'frontend_class'                => '',
                    'is_searchable'                 => '1',
                    'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
                    'is_comparable'                 => '1',
                    'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => '0',
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => '1',
                    'is_visible_on_front'           => '0',
                    'used_in_product_listing'       => '0',
                    'used_for_sort_by'              => '0',
                    'is_configurable'               => '0',
                    'is_filterable'                 => '0',
                    'is_filterable_in_search'       => '0',
                    'backend_type'                  => 'varchar',
                    'default_value'                 => '',
                    'is_user_defined'               => '0',
                    'is_visible'                    => '1',
                    'is_used_for_price_rules'       => '0',
                    'position'                      => '0',
                    'is_wysiwyg_enabled'            => '0',
                    'backend_model'                 => '',
                    'attribute_model'               => '',
                    'backend_table'                 => '',
                    'frontend_model'                => '',
                    'source_model'                  => '',
                    'note'                          => '',
                    'frontend_input_renderer'       => '',                      
                );

    // Now, overlay the incoming values on to the defaults.
    foreach($values as $key => $newValue)
        if(isset($data[$key]) == false)
        {
            echo "Attribute feature [$key] is not valid."."<br/>";
            return false;
        }

        else
            $data[$key] = $newValue;

    // Valid product types: simple, grouped, configurable, virtual, bundle, downloadable, giftcard
    $data['apply_to']       = $productTypes;
    $data['attribute_code'] = $attributeCode;
    $data['frontend_label'] = array(
                                        0 => $labelText,
                                        1 => '',
                                        3 => '',
                                        2 => '',
                                        4 => '',
                                    );

    //<<<<

    //>>>> Build the model.

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

    $model->addData($data);

    if($setInfo !== -1)
    {
        $model->setAttributeSetId($setInfo['SetID']);
        $model->setAttributeGroupId($setInfo['GroupID']);
    }

    $entityTypeID = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
    $model->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeID);

    $model->setIsUserDefined(1);

    //<<<<

    // Save.

    try
    {
        $model->save();
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        echo "Attribute [$labelText] could not be saved: " . $ex->getMessage()."<br/>";
        return false;
    }

    if(is_array($options)){
        foreach($options as $_opt){
            addAttributeValue($attributeCode, $_opt);
        }
    }

    $id = $model->getId();

    echo "Attribute [$labelText] has been saved as ID ($id).<br/>";

    // return $id;
}

function addAttributeValue($arg_attribute, $arg_value)
{
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    if(!attributeValueExists($arg_attribute, $arg_value))
    {
        $value['option'] = array($arg_value,$arg_value);
        $result = array('value' => $value);
        $attribute->setData('option',$result);
        $attribute->save();
    }

    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;
    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option)
    {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value)
        {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }
   return false;
}
function attributeValueExists($arg_attribute, $arg_value)
{
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option)
    {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value)
        {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

> NOTE: Allthough exceptions have been handled, Backup your Database
>   before you import these attributes, to be on safer side. Happy
>   Importing!

Thanks to :

- [Programatically create attribute in Magento, useful for the “on the fly” import system](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-create-attribute-in-magento-useful-for-the-on-the-fly-import-system/)
- [programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets)
- [Magento – Programmatically insert new attribute option](http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/magento-programmatically-insert-new-attribute-option/)

Comment: Remove the `'test'.` from line 54 of your export script and the export runs fine.

Comment: oops! I've removed "test" now :)

Comment: The import script results in a 500 server error.

Comment: I've placed the csv file and the importAttribute.php file in the /var/import dir of my magento installation but I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: any way to export attribute sets?

Comment: what about customer attributes? :)

Comment: @Haim I think i would prefer to create all atribute sets and attributes manually. This way you can check if you need to map old attributes to new existing attributes but with different name.

Comment: perfect explanation!!! +1 :)

Comment: Great script works good, In the above script I also need to  get the attribute description from eav_attibute_label table ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest part ist to take all the tables and copy them over.

Depending on whether you care about the other attributes (customer, addresses, order, ...) you can copy everything or just select the product attributes and insert them into the new database.

Check `eav_entity_type`, normally `catalog_product` is ID 4.

Then copy everything from `eav_attribute` and `catalog_eav_attribute` with `entity_type_id = 4` to you new instance. Becareful to not destroy the foreign keys.

**This is a problem, if you want to copy products too, because the IDs of the attributes might change!**