# Exporting and importing attributes and sets

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I'm looking to export all my product attributes and sets into a fresh install. But I'm struggling to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you Googled before posting? There is no built-in solution for this, but somebody has done it previously using some scripts. Check out the question below. It involves running scripts writing a file and reading that generated file. Seems pretty simple.

[how to export and import all attributes and attribute sets from one magento to other?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/how-to-export-and-import-all-attributes-and-attribute-sets-from-one-magento-to-o)

Fabian's answer might work as well. That one is more straightforward and involves just exporting and importing tables.

Comment: I tried this solution but it wouldnt update the default attr because they already exist. Such as color.