# How to export all the attribute and its options in magento 2

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento2.2.2, custom-attributes, attribute-set

I wish to export all the attribute and its options in magento 2 via script.
Please provide me a solution, How to export attributes and its options

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/BssGroup/magento-2-custom-product-attribute-export

Comment: If you can adapt this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/how-to-export-and-import-all-attributes-and-attribute-sets-from-one-magento-to-o to magento2 (there is also a lot of links to read)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and came here. The comment of nicolallias was actually helpful and solved my problem.

I Download and instaled this module
https://github.com/BssGroup/magento-2-custom-product-attribute-export

After installing the extension, go to Store ⇒ Configuration ⇒  BSS Extension ⇒ Product Export Column and in"Allowed Attributes", a list of all custom attribute will be shown. Admins can choose all or specific attributes which will be in separate columns while exporting products.

You can export the products as CSV from System-> Data Transfer -> Export.

Read this for more details.. https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-export-custom-product-attributes-in-magento-2/